# Slingshot search not working (not accepting keyboard input)

Tags: release-loki, slingshot, launcher

After a recent update, I can't search with the application launcher search bar anymore using the keyboard, because it won't accept input from the keyboard. Interestingly enough, I can type words elsewhere and paste it into the search bar, but I can't type directly in the search bar.

Any way I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here, in case someone else looks for a solution to this problem. Turns out, Slingshot doesn't play nice with ibus. All I had to do was run `killall ibus-daemon` from the command line to disable ibus, and the problem was fixed.